Does 億 rendaku like 六? (Or how to read something like 一億杯?)
六杯 reads ろっぱい because of rendaku. Does the same apply to 億 (おく)? In other words, does 一億杯 read like いちおっぱい? (Likewise, does 一億階 read like いちおっかい?)

「いちおっぱい」 is probably something very different!   ( . Y

Terminology check: 連濁【れんだく】 refers to cases where words 連 ("sequentially") 濁 ("muddy, soften" → here, "become voiced").  Things like the second toki becoming -doki in 時々 (tokidoki), or hon becoming -bon in 三本 (sanbon).  Cases where the second element in a compound doesn't become voiced, like roku + hai combining to become roppai, are not 連濁, since there is no voicing involved. Instead, these are called 促音【そくおん】 or "geminate consonants". See also the Japanese Wikipedia article on 促音.

@istrasci oh dear..... I suppose 一億杯 wouldn't be pronounced that way then...

The idea of having a hundred million cups somewhere is strange enough that I assumed you were asking specifically to check whether that pun would work....

@KarlKnechtel Nope... I wanted to know if 億 would 促音 like 六... so I needed an example of a counter that started with "h...", and 杯 was the first one that comes to mind...

The phenomenon you're referring to is gemination (促音化), not rendaku.
In the case of 回, I think いちおくかい and いちおっかい are equally natural. As for 一億杯, even native speakers rarely use such a combination, but both いちおくはい and いちおっぱい would be understood without any problem. Personally, I feel いちおくはい is safer.

Thanks for the clarification. I read that e.g. 三匹 = さんびき (and not さんひき) as a result of rendaku, and mistakenly thought that all such changes in pronounciation when a number is combined with a counter are results of rendaku...
